# Powershell Input Box - How to send the selection into the variable?

Tags: powershell, variables, customization, inputbox

I'm trying to create an interactive inputbox. Almost everything is working except one thing.

I don't manage to send the selection into the $z variable. (when I press the "OK" button)

Could you help me ?

This is only a function but the problem appears on all my functions. I guess there is something I'm missing.

```
[void] 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Sélection du cluster"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
{$z=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
{$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$z=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Dans quel cluster:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("CLUSTER")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("CLUSTER_01")

$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$z
```

Comment: I think you are sending it to a `$z` but it is not in the same scope. Use the `$objForm.Tag` or something similar to store the results and then you can access them outside the form execution. Else you _could_ use global variables but I don't recommmend it.

Comment: Looks like a scope issue. Try `$global:z = $objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()`. You may need to use `$global:z` at the bottom as well but don't think so as the variable doesn't exist in that scope.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the $global:z and it works.  But I don't understand why it's out of the scope. Could you explain me ?

Comment: Avoid using globals where you can. See my first comment. `$z` is undeclared before that script block is fired. If you declared it ahead of time it might work as I think it has access to the parent scope. Currently your are declaring `$z` in that script block scope so it dies after the block is fired.